# Get Error 502 when calling AWS API from browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I want to get an Item from my Database (DynamoDB) by calling the API Gateway which calls the Lambda function.

If I test my lambda function in AWS everything works fine. I can also get the data when I test the API Gateway in AWS.

But if I try to call the API from my frontend (javascript) I get an Error 502.

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

I did some research and thought maybe it has to be another dataType. But I also tried just to send a string as a response and its not working.

This is my frontend code:

```
$.ajax({
         method: 'GET',
         url: API_url,
         dataType: "jsonp",  
         "Content-Type":"application/json",     
         success: function(data) {
         console.log("responseAPI: ", data);
        },
       error: alert("fail")
     });
```

Lambda Function in AWS:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {


   var params={
       TableName: "testTable",
       Key: {
           "Username": "testUser@test.de"
       }
   } ;

  ddb.get(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
       callback(err, null)
   }
   else {
       callback(null, "Hello")
   };           // successful response
 })

};
```

Error 502

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Comment: Just to check, are you getting the 502 error from your lambda or from the DynamoDB call that your lambda makes?

Comment: i think the lambda is not the problem. Because i tested it in my management console in aws and it works fine. also if i test the API Gateway in AWS i get the data.

So i think it has to be something with the ajax.get?

I just tested it again with a string as a response and now its working. So i think it has to be something with the datatype right? Do you know what dataType is the correct one if i want to get my json object from my dynamoDB?

Comment: Navigate to your API gateway console, select the resource and you can find a Test button. You can see a detailed API GW execution logs over there. Can you post the same?